# My computer is not reading my newly installed processor right

Tags: cpu

I have just replaced my processor witch was a intel duo core 1.87, with a 
new intel duo core 2.66. My computer boots up fine with the new cpu installed
but when I go into the device manager to check witch cpu is installed it still
says that I have the intel duo core 1.87 installed. I really don't know what 
the problem is.

Comment: **Please don't repost the same question.** Instead, edit your existing question to add information. http://superuser.com/questions/848619/my-new-cpu-is-still-showing-up-as-if-i-have-the-old-cpu-in

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the help but I have restarted my pc went into the boot options
and saw that it showed the proper cpu unlike what the device manager showed 
previously. I went to the boot menu and hit save and it updated what I think 
was the bios. when I started my cpu up after this everything was fine the cpu 
was fine.

Comment: As a reminder, you can accept your own answer 48 hours after you posted the question.